# Catching errors in Promise, Observable.fromPromise() and subscribtion

Tags: node.js, promise, rxjs, try-catch

Long story short: I'm not sure what kind of errors should be catched in fromPromise().catch() method and what errors should be resolved in onError(error: Error) observer's method.

I use node.js with rxjs, that's why I'm converting my promises to observables.

Take a look at the classic Promise definition

```
const getPromise = (target) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(
            {
                url: url,
                json: true
            },
            (error, response, body) => {
                if (error) {
                    reject({
                        id: id,
                        error: error,
                        response: response,
                        body: body
                    });
                } else {
                    resolve({
                        id: id,
                        body: body
                    });
                }
            }
        );
    });
};
```

I'm converting my promises in the loop and returning observable array

```
const observableItems = [];
targetList.forEach((target) => {
  const observableItem = {
    id: target.id,
    observable$: rx.Observable
      .fromPromise(getPromise(target))
      .catch((error) => {
        // [1]
        return rx.Observable.of(error);
      })
  };
  observableItems.push(observableItem);
});

return observableItems;
```

And then I subscribe to my observables

```
observableItems.forEach((observableItem) => {
  const currentSubscribtion = observableItem.observable$.subscribe(
    (payload) => {
      if (payload && payload.error) {
        handleInvalidPayload(payload);
      } else {
        handleValidPayload(payload);
      }
    },
    (error) => {
      // [2]
    }
  );
  subscribtions.push(currentSubscribtion);
});
```

My questions:

1/ Is it possible to throw an error from [1] and pass it directly to the point [2]? At this moment I got if statement in onNext() - I don't like  it.

I tried to use return Observable.throw(someObject) in catch() method without any success.

2/ What kind of errors should be resolved in catch() and in OnError() method?

I'm asking about connection timeouts, ENOTFOUND and backend errors with codes like 404?

Comment: Just omit the `catch` completely if you're not handling/transforming anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purpose of `catch` operator is to handle upstream errors and substitute desired value into `observer::next` (or re-throw if needed).

for cases like

> Is it possible to throw an error from [1] and pass it directly to the point [2]?

, it seems you'd like to handle error in error observer directly. Which means you don't need to `catch` it, let rejection throws to error observer. Consider simple code snippet rejects immediately

```
const p = new Promise((res, rej) => rej(0));

Rx.Observable.fromPromise(p)
  .subscribe((x) => {}, (e) => console.log(e)); //0
```

next observer won't be called.

as said above, `catch` operator provieds mechanism to substitute errors as you want. say your rejected value is something you'd like to handle internally and pass forward, then you may return some values in catch to observer. It depends on nature of error you'd like to deal with, if you want to terminate observable stream with errored condition, you may not need catch it.